# Angular, bootstrap 4: Tab change event does not cause OnChange

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap navigation with tabs. In each tab I have a component, those are similar except `index` parameter. What I want to achieve is start loading data to a particular component, when its tab is opened.

I followed the idea to let the components get initialized (without loading data) and load the data when the particular tab is opened. For this aim I created a variable `selectedIndex`, which is passed to the tab component and is filled inside `show.bs.tab` event handler ([reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events)). I expected that whenever variable is changed, `OnChanged` function in tab component is processed and `selectedIndex` can be compared to `index`. But this never happens. It is processed, but only when another tab is opened, so it's one step delayed.

I tried also to call the `ChangeDetectorRef` and it works then, as expected. But I don't understand, why it doesn't work without this and I'd appreciate an explanation.

Or maybe another, better, approach?

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqxmre?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: To answer the question, it would be a very long reply. Instead, I suggest you check the lifecycle hook of angular to see how `ngOnChanges` and `ngAfterViewInit` work together, how often do they run. Also, you're mixing jquery with angular, which is discourage. With this tab example, you can accomplish it with ViewChildren and ContentChildren